# How to implement refresh token in Next.js using NextAuth?

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt, refresh-token, next-auth

I have implemented a simple authentication procedure using nextAuth,
now I want to implement the refresh token procedure so the user can get e a new access token,
the nextauth file provides documentation regarding implementation of refresh token using google, but I am currently using CredentialProvider
[nextAuth documentation about refresh token](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/refresh-token-rotation)

**[...nextauth].js file**

```
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const user = await axios.post(
            `${process.env.API_URL}/auth/authentication/login`,
            {
              email: credentials.email,
              password: credentials.password,
            }
          );

          if (!user.data.user) {
            return null;
          }

          if (user.data.user) {
            return {
              id: user.data.user.id,
              name: user.data.user.name,
              surname: user.data.user.surname,
              email: user.data.user.email,
              role: user.data.user.role,
            };
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.name = user.name;
        token.surname = user.surname;
        token.email = user.email;
        token.role = user.role;
      }
      return token;
    },
    session: ({ session, token }) => {
      if (token) {
        session.id = token.id;
        session.name = token.name;
        session.surname = token.surname;
        session.email = token.email;
        session.role = token.role;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    encryption: true,
    maxAge: 5 * 60 * 1000,
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

With the credentials provider, the mechanics are the same to refresh a token. Here is your code with some example code added to it (see the comments).
When you check for values in the `jwt` callback, that's where you can also check for its validity and call your endpoint for refresh.

```js
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const user = await axios.post(
            `${process.env.API_URL}/auth/authentication/login`,
            {
              email: credentials.email,
              password: credentials.password,
            }
          );

          if (!user.data.user) {
            return null;
          }

          if (user.data.user) {
            return {
              id: user.data.user.id,
              name: user.data.user.name,
              surname: user.data.user.surname,
              email: user.data.user.email,
              role: user.data.user.role,
            };
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.name = user.name;
        token.surname = user.surname;
        token.email = user.email;
        token.role = user.role;
      }
      // Here, check the token validity date
      if (token.tokenExpiration < Date.now()) {
        // Call the endpoint where you handle the token refresh for a user
        const user = await axios.post(
            `${process.env.API_URL}/auth/authentication/refresh`,
            {
              refreshToken: token.refreshToken
            }
          );
        // Check for the result and update the data accordingly
        return {...token, ...user};
      }
      return token;
    },
    session: ({ session, token }) => {
      if (token) {
        session.id = token.id;
        session.name = token.name;
        session.surname = token.surname;
        session.email = token.email;
        session.role = token.role;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    encryption: true,
    maxAge: 5 * 60 * 1000,
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
  },
});
```